# Hiding sections in Infopath

Tags: infopath

I might be doing something particularly silly here, but no matter how I create my Infopath form, when I hide one section it hides *all* the sections.

I am trying to create a form with multiple permutations so that different fields will appear depending on the user's answers. Therefore, I want nothing but the basic initial fields to show in the beginning, with other fields being "unhidden" as more information is entered.

However, I can't get near achieving this as anytime I try to hide a field initially, it hides everything.

I am trying to put each new option in its own section and apply the rules to the sections.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sections to unhide individually, you'll need to have some sort of status field for each section so that when all the required fields have been filled out, the status field for that section is flipped and then unhides the section.

So a rough example 3 sections 1, 2, and 3. You would have a status field for sections 2 and 3. When all fields in section 1 are answered appropriately, a rule set section 2 status field. Section 2 listens on this field and when the right condition is met will unhide the section. When all fields in section 2 are filled out, this triggers the section 3 trigger field to change and thus unhides section 3.